# Update Mongoose: Help on how to update document in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am newbie and working for my thesis.
I was able to create insert and delete function but getting issues updating the data.

The below is the code under the controllers folder:

Insert Document:

```
module.exports.register = (params) => {
    let user = new User({
        firstName: params.firstName,
        lastName: params.lastName,
        department: params.department,
        position: params.position,
        email: params.email,
        mobileNo: params.mobileNo,
        password: bcrypt.hashSync(params.password, 10),
        isAdmin: params.isAdmin,
        departments: {
            departmentId: params.departmentId
        }
    })

    return user.save().then((user, err) => {
        return (err) ? false : true
    })
}
```

Delete Document:

```
module.exports.deleteUser = (params) => {
    return User.findByIdAndRemove(params.userId).then((user, err) => {
        return (err) ? false : true
    })
}
```

While the below is the code for the routers:

Insert Document:

```
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    UserController.register(req.body).then(result => res.send(result))
});
```

Delete Document:

```
router.delete('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
    let userId = req.params.id
    UserController.deleteUser({userId}).then(user => res.send(user))
});
```

What I've tried to far is to use the delete logic but instead of findOneAndRemove, I used findOneAndUpdate but it's not updating the data. It just sending true value but not updating the document.

I've also tried some of the logic in YouTube and some here but it doesn't matched the way we construct the data so I'm having difficulties understanding them.

The target is to update the same values in the register using the id of the user.

I'm trying to update using this code:

Controllers:

```
module.exports.updateUser = (params) => {
    return User.findOneAndUpdate(params.userId, (user, err) => {
        return (err) ? false : true
    })
}
```

Routes:

```
router.post('/update/:id', (req, res) => {
    UserController.updateUser(req.params.id).then(user => res.send(user))
});
```

I've also tried to add the parameters but it's not working. What I want to update is the whole details example:

```
        firstName: params.firstName,
        lastName: params.lastName,
        department: params.department,
        position: params.position,
        email: params.email,
        mobileNo: params.mobileNo,
        password: bcrypt.hashSync(params.password, 10),
        isAdmin: params.isAdmin,
        departments: {
            departmentId: params.departmentId
        }
```

Sample User:

```
{
    "userId": "60f649bd8896c80004b3ffbe",
    "firstName": "Jane",
    "lastName": "Joe",
    "department": "Accounting",
    "position": "head",
    "email": "janedoe@mail.com",
    "mobileNo": "0",
    "password": "pass123",
    "isAdmin": "yes",
    "departments": {
        "departmentId": "60efcbec769cf60004b85319"
    }
}
```

Here's my update code:
Controller:

```
module.exports.updateUserData = (params) => {
    const dataToUpdate = {
        firstName: params.firstName,
            lastName: params.lastName,
            department: params.department,
            position: params.position,
            email: params.email,
            mobileNo: params.mobileNo,
            password: bcrypt.hash(params.password, 10),
            isAdmin: params.isAdmin,
            departments: {
                departmentId: params.departmentId
            }
       }
    
    User.findOneAndUpdate({userId:params.userId}, {$set:dataToUpdate}, {new: true}, (err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
        }
        console.log(doc);
    });
}
```

Routers:

```
router.post('/update-user/:id', (req, res) => {
    let userId = req.params.id;
    UserController.updateUserData({userId}).then(doc => res.send(doc))
})
```

Using this code I am getting error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined under routers folder.

Comment: How you are trying to update?

Comment: This has been updated. Please see the above details. I want to update the whole details based on the registration data.

Answer (score 0):

You should try following. It might meet your requirement

```
 const dataToUpdate = {
        firstName: params.firstName,
            lastName: params.lastName,
            department: params.department,
            position: params.position,
            email: params.email,
            mobileNo: params.mobileNo,
            password: bcrypt.hashSync(params.password, 10),
            isAdmin: params.isAdmin,
            departments: {
                departmentId: params.departmentId
            }
       }
    
    User.findOneAndUpdate({userId:params.userId}, {$set:dataToUpdate}, {new: true}, (err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
        }
    
        console.log(doc);
    });
```

Comment: I appreciate this @Arvind. But could you please provide me a guide on how to create my controllers and routes. I've tried to import them but I'm getting errors with TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined with my routes.

Comment: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'params' before initialization backend\routes\user.js:18:14

Comment: I just used your code and I am no longer getting errors after some modifications and it is now displaying the data in my console but yet not update the data.

Comment: The issue now it's not updating the data filtered by ID but it's updating the first document in my user database.

Comment: can you share one user document from user collections

Comment: post updated please refer to the above. It's almost working but it's only update the first document in my user database. Aside from that, when I use params it returns null so I changed it to req.body. I'm using postman to test the code.

Comment: looks fine , It should work, what is params.userId in this case

Comment: I would like to update this: 60f649bd8896c80004b3ffbe. I mean the above user but it keeps on updating the first document which is 60e41b868d40830004619b17. Maybe there's something wrong with my routers. I didn't use controllers this time and used your code under routers folder.

Comment: It's working but not updating the correct user. It's only updates the first document in my user database. I will post my router and controllers folder.